# RMarkdown: How to pass arguments to bash chunk defined as variables in R?

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown

[Cross-posted](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-pass-arguments-to-bash-chunk-defined-as-variables-in-r/123755)

I want to use variables defined in R environment as an argument in the bash chunk. Is there any way to do that?

For instance, in the examples below I want to use R to define the path to the script and pass it as an argument to bash:

````
```{r}
path_to_script <- glue("{here::here()}/bash_scripts/script.sh")
\```

```{bash}
bash  **path_to_script**
\```
````

Comment: Well, I don;t know R but it seems to have escape functions for shell, which you will 100% need to use:  https://rdrr.io/r/base/shQuote.html

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the knitr `bash` engine does any substitutions, but you should be able to write to an environment variable, and use that from bash.

For example,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "09/12/2021"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
msg <- shQuote("This is a message from R.")
Sys.setenv(R_MESSAGE = msg)
```

```{bash}
echo $R_MESSAGE
```
````

which produces this output:

[image]

I added the `shQuote()` call after reading @Fravadona's comment:  it is definitely a really good idea, since the path you are constructing may contain spaces or other special characters.

Comment: No, `shQuote` is not needed with your method, that is, if you expand the environment variable inside double-quotes: `echo "$R_MESSAGE"`

Comment: @Fravadona, I was thinking of Oleg's example, where the text in the environment variable could contain characters which `bash` would see as special.  Would `bash "$R_MESSAGE"` ignore those, or act on them?

Comment: It depends on when `$R_MESSAGE` is expanded: if it's **before** calling bash, then you'll need `shQuote`. if it's expanded **by** bash, then double quotes are enough

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @user2554330 for your suggestion. Indeed it seems to be working in the way I explained in my question. However, a little simpler solution was suggested [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-pass-arguments-to-bash-chunk-defined-as-variables-in-r/123755). Namely, don't use a bash chunk and instead create a string with full command and pass it to the `system()` function in R. In this case, I can do everything within the same environment.

````
```{r}
path_to_script <- glue("{here::here()}/bash_scripts/script.sh")
arg1 <- "something"
full_command <- glue("bash {path_to_script} {arg1}")
system(full_command)
```
````

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable, but don't skip the quoting with `shQuote()`.  If `here::here()` returns something containing special characters (e.g. spaces would be pretty common on Windows) it won't be executed properly.